# Unable to unlock disk after enabling FileVault2

Tags: macos, mac, macbook-pro, filevault

I just enabled FileVault2 with my personal account. After the necessary reboot my user is not able to unlock the disk which just started to be encrypted.
The only way to get access to my computer is to quickly lock in with another user account to unlock the hard drive, log back out and now log in to my normal account.

I already tried an approach I found while googling which advised to remove my user account's password which automaticlly removes the ability to unlock the disk. Then I rebootet, reset a password and enabled my account to unlock the disk via the standard dialog in the system preferences but this makes the system preferences crash. If it makes any sense to append the crash report to this question, let me know.

Any help or approach to resolving the problem will be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Filevault2.

I'm German as well. :) What happens here is that the **keyboard is reset to the US keyboard layout**. As the keys are changed - especially non alphabetic keys - you're probably typing a different password.

You can enable to show the input method in *System Preferences > User & Groups > Login Options*. Then change it to German upon reboot.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I would have never ever thought of that. Do know whether Apple already knows about the bug?

Comment: @LukasSpieß Sorry, I don't know. I'm not a developer that can see such information.